# Fabric JS: modifying a group sets the individual objects to have the wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Let's say we have an object at left = 100, right = 100. If I select the object as a part of a group, and modifies the group, the left and right get set to left = 0, right = 0 or something similar. Shouldn't modifying a group change the coordinates of the individual objects in the group to have the proper coords?